# Laravel 4 setting up model using the IoC container

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I recently watched this video and wanted to change my [Laravel](https://vimeo.com/53029232) controllers so that they had their dependencies managed with Laravel's IoC container. The video talks about creating an interface for a Model and then implementing that interface for the specific data source used.

My question is: when implementing the interface with a class that extends Eloquent and binding that class to the controller so that it is accessible from `$this->model`, should I also create interfaces and implementations for the Eloquent models which may be returned when calling methods such as `$this->model->find($id)`? Should there be different classes for the Model and the ModelRepository?

Put it another way: how do I do `new Model` when my model is in `$this->model`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, yes, people doing that pattern (the repository pattern) have an interface which have some methods defined that your app will use:

```
interface SomethingInterface {

    public function find($id);

    public function all();

    public function paged($offset, $limit);

}
```

Then you create an implementation of this. If you're using Eloquent, then you can make an Eloquent implementation

```
use Illuminate\Database\Model;

class EloquentSomething {

    protected $something;

    public function __construct(Model $something)
    {
        $this->something = $something;
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        return $this->something->find($id);
    }

    public function all() { ... }

    public function paged($offset, $limit) { ... }

}
```

Then you make a service provider to put it all together, and add it into `app/config/app.php`.

```
use Something; // Eloquent Model
use Namespace\Path\To\EloquentSomething;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RepoServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $app = $this->app;

        $app->bind('Namespace/Path/To/SomethingInterface', function()
        {
            return new EloquentSomething( new Something );
        });
    }

}
```

Finally, your controller can use that interface as a type hint:

```
use Namespace/Path/To/SomethingInterface;

class SomethingController extends BaseController {

    protected $something;

    public function __construct(SomethingInterface $something)
    {
         $this->something = $something;
    }


    public function home() { return $this->something->paged(0, 10); }

}
```

That should be it. Apologies on any errors, this isn't tested, but is something I do a lot.

**Downsides:**

More code :D

**Upsides:**

- Able to switch out implementations (instead of EloquentSomething, can use ArraySomething, MongoSomething, whatever), without changing your controller code or any code that uses an implementation of your interface.
- Testable - you can mock your Eloquent class and test the repository, or  mock your constructor dependency and test your controller
- Re-usable - you can `App::make()` to get the concrete EloquentSomething anywhere in your app and re-use the Something repository anywhere in your code
- Repository is a good place to add additional logic, like a layer of cacheing, or even validation rules. Stock mucking about in your controllers.

**Finally:**, since I likely typed all that out and STILL DIDN'T ANSWER YOUR QUESTION (wtf?!), you **can** get a new instance of the model using `$this->model`. Here's an example for creating a new Something:

```
// Interface:
public function create(array $data);

// EloquentSomething:
public function create(array $data) 
{
    $something = this->something->newInstance();
    // Continue on with creation logic
}
```

Key is this method, [newInstance()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L322).

Comment: Thank you, this helped me too! I was calling EloquentSomething's create() from a Controller loop using $something = $this->model as @user1669496 mentioned which resulted in creation of $something with the first iteration, then updating the $something with each subsequent iteration (when I had intended to create a new $something with each iteration). Amending this to $something = this->something->newInstance() as suggested resulted in my intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `$newModel = $this->model` and it's worked for me.